# Body scrolls with nav open in iOS only

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I've made a responsive website and when I open the nav, if I try to scroll, the body continues to scroll. Obviously **I would the body scroll blocked when the nav is open.**

I used jQuery and I added `overflow: hidden` when I open the nav, and `overflow: auto` when I close the nav. **It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Android (Samsung browser, etc) but it doesn't work on iOS (iPad, iPhone).**

I've also tried `scrollTo` with Javascript but it is not supported on iOS too.

I tried also to play with `position: fixed` but I have the problem with the body jumping on top of the page when I open the nav.

**NB: you have to switch the snippet to "full page" and resize the browser to (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) to be able to test the open-nav button.**

How could I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".open-nav").click(function() {
        $(".main-nav").fadeToggle(500);
        $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
        $(".open-nav").css("display", "none");
        $(".close-nav").css("display", "block");
      });
      
      $(".close-nav").click(function() {
        $(".main-nav").fadeToggle(500);
        $("body").css("overflow-y", "visible");
        $(".close-nav").css("display", "none");
        $(".open-nav").css("display", "block");
      });
    });
```

```css
html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: grey;
      z-index: 9999;
    }

    .open-nav {
      width: 60px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: red;
      display: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .close-nav {
      width: 60px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: green;
      display: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .main-nav {
      float: right;
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .main-nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .main-nav ul li {
      float: left;
      padding: 0 15px;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a {
      font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a:hover {
      border-bottom: solid #ff0054 2px;
    }

    .active {
      border-bottom: solid #ff0054 2px;
    }
    
    #hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    }

    #hero h1 {
    margin-top: 90px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    }

    #hero p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    }


    /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and 992px)*/

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
      a.open-nav {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      a.close-nav {
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .main-nav {
        display: none;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: none;
        z-index: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        margin-left: -50vw;
        margin-right: -50vw;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .main-nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 25%;
      }
      .main-nav ul li {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .main-nav ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 26px;
        margin: 0 30px 60px 30px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <a class="open-nav col-xs-3 hidden-md" title="Menu">Click to Open</a>
          <a class="close-nav col-xs-3 hidden-md" title="Menu">Click to Close</a>
          <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html" class="active" title="Home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <section id="hero">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
              <h1>Title</h1>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </section>
       <section id="text">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
              <h3>Title 2</h3>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't appear to display any of the behaviour you describe (in any browser) and there is no scrolling logic at all in your code. As such it's difficult to understand exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I'm sorry @RoryMcCrossan maybe the question and the code are not clear.
I would just know if there is another solution instead of overflow: hidden that works on iOS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you have to switch the snippet to "full page" and resize the browser to `(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px)` to be able to test the `open-nav` button. However I still agree with you, the snippet is not fully testable because the body is empty and so we cannot scroll. The explanations lack some details about expected behaviour and current one too IMO.

Comment: I've added some elements in the body. So now is possible to scroll.